# Anaconda prompt can't see my network drives when launch as Admin

Tags: anaconda

I have installed anaconda (last version) on my work laptop.
The only directory were I am allowed to work is a network one, mapped to the H: letter.

I also have to launch the prompt as admin if I want to use jupyter lab (if not there is a WinError 5 access denied).

Without the admin rights :

[image: Without the admin rights]

But with admin rights only the prompt can't see the H: drive

[image: With admin rights, can't see the H: Drive]

So I am stuck:

- without the admin rights I can go in my H: but I can't launch jupyter lab
- with the admin rights, I can launch jupyter lab but I can't go to my drive !

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your question can be found [here](https://superuser.com/questions/690287/command-prompt-in-administrator-mode-doesnt-see-mapped-drives). It's because starting a command prompt "As Administrator" it's running in a different user context than when you don't.